# Why doesn't Barry shoot his shotgun sometimes?

Tags: jetpack-joyride

I noticed something different in Jetpack Joyride. Until now, when you were riding the *Bad as hog*, Barry would shoot his shotgun at scientists (complete with a one-handed *Terminator*-style swing reload), but now it seems he just runs over them.

Was this an intended change implemented in a recent update oris it an issue only I experience? Was the game censored or something?

Comment: Maybe just a creative decision? Or a change to satisfy a lower ESRB — or similar international entity — rating?

Comment: They did alter a few things before the game was released, for example, the name was originally "Machine Gun Jetpack" and the Bad-Ass-Hog from Monster Dash turned into Bad as Hog. I just wonder what made them change this months after release.

Comment: Pretty sure Machine Gun Jetpack was ditched as a name because JJ is catchier and there's not just ONE jetpack anymore. Bad Ass Hog was probably censored but might just be for the pun. The games did used to be a bit more violent/graphic like Age of Zombies

Comment: From anyone who voted to close this, I would like to know what do you think is "not constructive" in this question and what can be done, if anything, to improve it.

Comment: I think the "censorship" part was making people think that, edited the title to reflect your question (as I read it) and left the possibility of censorship in the Q rather than the title.

Comment: What jketpack are you using by the way? See my updated answer for my recent results, seems to be based on the jetpack you're wearing, possibly other items.

Comment: In my screenshots and below answer I was wearing the "machine gun" jetpack for what its worth.  I believe that is what it is called - it's the starter one.

Comment: I just checked, it seems to be dependent on jetpack, like you suggested. I use the piggy-bank one, but when I switched to the machinegun one he started shooting again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I noticed this same problem immediately after updating. It seems to be a gltich, after one run with no shotgun Barry has been shooting scientists every time with the hog. Not sure what makes him not shoot, however.

Confirmed just now, version 1.31(1)*. I wore the Barry's Head/Suit and Machinegun Jetpack items if it made a difference, and used the Free Ride gadget to ensure I'd get a vehicle. In the 2 runs I got a Hog, both times Barry used his Shotgun like he used to.

---

A totally scientific sample of 5 tests seems to indicate that **this is caused by your jetpack**. With the Golden Piggy Pack Barry doesn't shoot scientists on the Hog, with the Machine Gun Jetpack, Laser Jetpack and Rainbow Jetpack he DOES shoot scientists. He did this twice on each jetpack, so I'm pretty sure this is the cause. As to why, I have no idea. The Golden Piggy Pack is the only jetpack I saw that makes Barry not shoot.

Comment: That's the same version playing. I think it's a bug

Comment: @JohnoBoy I only noticed it once the very first time. Have you seen it more than once?

Comment: I don't see the shotgun animation anymore

Comment: This looks to the cause to the issue, but I can't understand why sometimes Barry will shoot the scientists even when using the Piggy Bank (I seen him shoot once when he pciks up the hog then stop for the rest of the ride)

Answer (score 3):

Unless,there has been a recent update not yet pushed to my phone, I think what you describe is still the basic look.  Here is a screenshot from my phone showing the Hog with the shotgun.  The screen shot doesn't show it, but Barry still shoots at the scientists as he drives on my device.

[image: BadAsHog]
**Edit:** Here is another screen cap where I actually captured the shot as it appears on my device.  Based on this I think your question is either device specific to iPad, or a bug rather than censorship.

[image: HogShot]

Comment: What version are you running? I think on 1.3 he still shot but on the later version (Retina iPad update) they removed this

Comment: How do I check my version?  I looked but couldn't see it in game.  I'm playing on an iPhone 4s...

Comment: On the main screen, choose credits scroll down, right at the end, after the Special Thanks section

Comment: I am on 1.3.1 (1) based on the credits.

Comment: It is *hard* to get a screenshot of that, isn't it :)?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes he does not shoot because he's reloading or jumping at the time.